# Use protractor to test login on non-AngularJS page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I have an AngularJS app which authenticates using oAuth SSO at GitHub. I am trying to figure out a way to use protractor and automate the login tests. I cannot figure out how to retrieve a non-angular field and how to manage wait'ing for the page to load with `browser.driver`, My spec looks like this:

```
// Create a repository                                                                                                                     
describe('login', function() {

  it('should login', function() {
      // this issues a redirect to GitHub
      browser.driver.get( process.env.HOST + '/auth/github' ) 
      browser.sleep( 4000 ); // Sleep to make sure page loads fully..                                                                      
      // browser.debugger(); // tried to use debugger...                                                                                   
      var login = element( by.id( "login_field" ) );
      login.sendKeys( process.env.USERNAME );
      var password = element( by.id( "password" ) );
      password.sendKeys( process.env.PASSWORD )
  });                                                                                                                                      
});
```

I run the command like this:

```
HOST=http://someserver.com.dev USERNAME=foobar PASSWORD=barfoo protractor config/protractor.conf
```

How can I properly load the authenticate page, enter the correct information into the fields, and then wait for redirection back into my Angularized application (I can handle things from there).

I tried to use the debugger to jump into this code, but it was not intuitive for me. When the debugger blocked, I did not seem to be inside my code, but inside of cli.js. If I hit 'c' then my script continued all the way to execution and failed without blocking further. Am I misunderstanding where to use the debugger command inside my script? And, from the Chrome inspector I hoped to to use  `window.clientSideScripts.findInputs` but was thwarted there as well; these seem to be for AngularJS elements, not elements which are not angularized.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Testing non-angular pages with Protractor can be tricky regarding waiting for stuff.

I suggest you upgrade Protractor to [latest](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases) (1.5.0 as of now), use a [custom function waitReady()](https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb) that `browser.wait` for elements ready and rewrite your test like below.

```
// TODO: use page objects
var loginNameInputElm = $('#login_field'); // or element(by.id('login_field'))
var passwordInputElm = $('#password'); // same as element(by.id('password'))
var loginBtnElm = $('button[type=submit]');

it('non-angular page so ignore sync and active wait to load', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    browser.get(process.env.HOST + '/auth/github');
    expect(loginNameInputElm.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(passwordInputElm.waitReady()).toBeTruthy();
});

it('should fill user and password and logins', function() {
    loginNameInputElm.sendKeys(process.env.USERNAME);
    passwordInputElm.sendKeys(process.env.PASSWORD);
    loginBtnElm.click();
});

it('restores ignore sync when switching back to angular pages', function() {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false; // restore
    browser.get('/some-angular-page');
});
```

More details of why `waitReady` [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1557).

Note: in the past I've suggested setting a high implicit, e.g.

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

That *hack* allows to you avoid `waitReady` and keep using the standard

```
expect(loginNameInputElm.isPresent()).toBeTruthy();
```

But has an ugly disadvantage when testing for elements **NOT** present, i.e. when testing for absent or non visible elements in which case it will wait 5 seconds (5000ms) in vane, e.g. when doing

```
expect(someNonExistingElm.isPresent()).toBeFalsy();
```

Comment: You need to incorporate a snippet, is not built-in Protractor by default. Snippet at https://gist.github.com/elgalu/2939aad2b2e31418c1bb

Comment: thank you for your reply. I saw this "Add `require('./waitReady.js');` in your onPrepare block or file." in the link.  Does that mean I need to use RequireJS to require the snippet?

Comment: `require()` is part of NodeJS already. Protractor runs in node (not in the browser) take a look at the docs to get more familiar ;)

Comment: @LeoGallucci element(by.id('login_field')) is a protractor function which can not be used on non angular pages. $('#login_field') is giving undefined. How to waitReady for a element on non angular Page ?