# Why must I use browser.sleep while writing protractor tests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My first run at E2E tests.  I'm trying to digest someone else's protractor tests.

**Problem:** There are a lot of `browser.driver.sleep` and this seems fragile.

**Goal:** not to use `browser.driver.sleep`

**Question:**  What is a better approach to `browser.driver.sleep`?  Something less fragile like a promise or something I dont know about lol?

```
var config = require('../../protractor.conf.js').config;
describe('this Homepage Body Tests', function(){
browser.driver.get(config.homepageUrl);

it("should open find a clinic page", function(){
  // page loads :: want to fix this random wait interval 
  browser.driver.sleep(2000);
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

  var string = 'clinic';
  var main = '.search-large-text';
  var link = element(by.cssContainingText('.submenu li a', string));

  link.click().then(function() {
    // page reloads :: want to fix this random wait interval
    browser.driver.sleep(3000);
    var title = element(by.cssContainingText(main, string));
    expect(title.getText()).toBe(string);
  });
});
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since there is an `ignoreSynchronization` turned on, you cannot use `waitForAngular()`, which would be a solution in case of an angular-site testing.

A better solution here would be to set a *page load timeout*:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10000);  // 10 seconds
```

See also these relevant threads on explicit waits and timeouts:

- [Use protractor to test login on non-AngularJS page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22239207/use-protractor-to-test-login-on-non-angularjs-page) (Leo's answer is very detailed)
- [Protractor : How to wait for page complete after click a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748442/protractor-how-to-wait-for-page-complete-after-click-a-button)
- [Timeouts](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts)

Comment: Yeah unfortunatly as we pivot our site fully to angular the homepage is still in rails.