# Protractor timeouts

Tags: angularjs, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I've been developing automated tests in Protractor for quite some time and like many of you, I've run into gaps which can only be crossed with the `browser.sleep()`-bridge. I'm not a fan of hard coding things such as this but if it's a necessity I will.

The tests I've developed have brought me to a point where every `browser.sleep(1000)` has a major impact on my runtime. The tests are currently testing permissions for different accounts (128 exactly) and this involves logging in and out whilst checking what every account has and has not received access to.

The website I'm testing is a pure AngularJS application which, in my eyes, should make `browser.sleep()` a deprecated method since there is a `browser.waitForAngular()` method that accurately waits until the page is fully loaded compared to `browser.sleep()` which waits a set amount of time and if your website isn't loaded within that time (it happens), you'll have an inconsistent test (nobody likes inconsistency).

Research has led me to believe that `browser.waitForAngular()` does not take into account animations and related time-consuming features since they're not AngularJS related yet this is not implemented in our website. Also `waitForAngular()` basically waits for `$digest`, `$http`, and `$timeout`.

What I'm asking is wether this is something which is regarded as an acceptable loss since Protractor is great in general or is there something I'm overlooking here?

TL;DR: 
Are there solutions out there to allow us not to settle for `browser.sleep()`?

Sources: [Protractor Timeout Docs](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#timeouts),
[Timeout-spec.js (protractor docs)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/debugging/timeout_spec.js),
[Issue909](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/909), [Issue279](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/279), [Issue92](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/92), [StackQuestion1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27240744/why-must-i-use-browser-sleep-while-writing-protractor-tests)

Comment: I've been experiencing the same intermittent timeouts that are blamed in the FAQ on use of $timeout for polling. I wander if its fail also in the cases its not polling. For my team it comes more to light as we rely on the Angular Material components. They are heavy on animation interactions with heavy use of $timeout(func, 0).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can devise some sort of test to determine if whatever you're waiting for has completed, you can use [`browser.wait`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait). Taking ideas from from http://docsplendid.com/archives/209, you can pass a function that returns a promise that resolves to `true` or `false`, such as one that uses [`isPresent`](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent)

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent();
}, 1000);
```

or if you have some more complicated condition you can use promise chaining:

```
browser.wait(function() {
  return element(by.id('some-element')).isPresent().then(function(isPresent) {
    return !isPresent;
  });
}, 1000);
```

and the command flow will wait, repeatedly calling the function passed to `wait`, until the promise it returns resolves to `true`.

Comment: You can also use ExpectedConditions to wait for things such as element is present, is clickable, contains text, etc cf http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions

Answer (score 0):

This is the way if you want to perform any action when element present or want to wait until it present on page.

```
    element(by.id).isPresent().then(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                nextButton.click();
            }
            else{
                browser.wait(function () {
                    return browser.isElementPresent(element(by.id));
                },50000);
            }
        }).then(function () {
            nextButton.click();
        });

    },
```